# css is there a way to aligh these two div horizantally

Tags: html, css

This is a jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6Ebzy/1/

This is the result
[image]

**Please in order to see a good fiddle, try to maximize the width and the high of the window that shows the result in the jfiddle**

is there a way to align the text in the left with the form in the right? without using specific pixles (because I need to take care if the user minimize the window)

I would like to have something like this:
[image]

The div in the left is

```
.validationClass{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

the form has this css:

```
#msform {

    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
    width: 40%;/*totti 600px*/
    margin: auto auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Please I need the bar that has the number to **keep** in the msform

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just add `position:relative` and `top` in this class:

```
.validationClass{
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 70px;
float: left;
text-align: center;   
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ebzy/4/)

Or you want something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ebzy/7/) ?

Then you have to change the following:

```
#msform fieldset {
background: white;
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
padding: 20px 30px;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
/* margin: 0 10%; */
position: relative;
left: 60%;
top: -20px;
}

.validationClass {
width: 55%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 70px;
}

#progressbar {
margin-bottom: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
counter-reset: step;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
left:58%;
position: absolute;
}
```

Add this in your `html`

```
<div class="body">
    <ul>
        <li class="error">The first name field is required.</li><li class="error">The last name field is required.</li>
        <li class="error">The mobile number field is required.</li>
        <li class="error">The password must be at least 8 characters.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear:left;"></div><!---add this --->
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ebzy/8/)

Comment: this is what I told you that I don't want to use. using a top in pixles will not solve the problem, it will solve it just temporary, but If i resize the window, your solutoin won't work at all

Comment: Hmm can i change your html?

Comment: you could change the html, but please don't change anything inside the form. you can change out side it

Comment: You want as first or second fiddle i posted?

Comment: the first one and I appreciat your help and time and efforts

Comment: Tell me if now is ok. Tested in some resolutions.

Comment: Of course. Keep the `css` changes from my first example and add the `div` with `clear:left` `style` in your `html` :) Do you want to delete my second example?